# Verb to "make something succeed"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I would like a verb that would express the idea of making something succeed.

Example: I [my-verb] the unit tests.

Writing "I made the unit tests succeed." is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I succeded in passing the tests/ I passed the tests successfully/ I managed to pass the tests successfully.

Comment: In your sentence, what is succeeding? You, or the tests? Two answers below take it that *you* are succeeding in the tests, whereas your own sentence implies that the tests are successful. If *I* is the subject of your verb, what is the object?

Comment: The tests are succeeding. I am doing the action of making them succeed.

Comment: I don't think there will be anything like a single-word verb for this. Part of the problem is OP isn't actually doing *anything* to the tests themselves apart from ***running them*** (repeatedly, in an "edit-and-retest" cycle, if they aren't successful). If we had a transitive verb for the process, it would take the ***thing/software item being tested*** as an object. One figurative usage in that general area is *"I **nursed** the application through the unit tests"* (which implies it didn't succeed right away; I had to make changes before it passed).

Comment: The two actions that most commonly make unit tests succeed are *I updated the unit tests* and *I fixed the unit tests*. That's assuming that you made them pass by modifying the tests themselves and not the application they're testing

Comment: I successfully **ran** the tests (via FumbleFingers comment)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [pass](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pass):

> - to undergo an examination or a trial with favorable results. (TFD)

- I passed the unit tests.

Comment: The software passed the unit tests, not him.

Comment: @MatthewRead - OP provided information later...

Answer (score 1):

You could try the verb **accomplished**, which means completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There is the verb *succeed*.

> succeed - "if you succeed, you achieve something that you have been
>   aiming for, and if a plan or piece of work succeeds, it has the
>   results that you wanted", e. g. She's been trying to pass her driving test for six years and she's finally succeeded. (Cambridge Dictionary Online)

However, it is the intransitive verb, so, cannot be used with the object in your sentence. The transitive verb *pass* or *come through* should be used instead.

Comment: Respectfully, your actual answer [*pass or come through* ] comes last - you should lead with it, and define w/link.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is probably [fine-tune](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fine-tune); `to make fine adjustments to (something) in order to obtain optimum performance` (dictionary.reference.com).Thus,I **fine-tuned** the unit tests.